# Text inside bars dynamic and responsive

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve something like this:[image]

Im trying to have the bars dynamic in addition to the length of the text and it should be fully responsive. Im interested in your approaches.

Comment: "Im interested in your approaches" is an interesting way to express "I want you to write code for me"...

Comment: nothing bad about that since the code I tried so far doesnt bring up the expected result and besides that the given solution is way different I was expecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this would do the trick.

The background for inline-elements (such as `span`) renders exactly the way you need it.
You just should add some padding for the `span` itself and set a bigger line-height for spacing the lines.

```css
.wrapper {
  line-height: 2;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

span {
  padding-block: 6px;
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<p class="wrapper">
  <span>Hello World<br>This is my task For you<br>guys, hope you enjoy it</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:flex-start;
  font-weight:bold;
}
.res{
  background-color: gainsboro;
  padding:0.5rem;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="res">Hello World </p>
  <p class="res">This is my Task for you </p>
  <p class="res">guys, hope you enjoy it </p>
</div>
```